# Is there MySQL.. INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY SELECT?

Tags: mysql

is there a way to do an INSERT but on DUPLICATE KEY instead of an update do a SELECT?

Comment: What exactly is your use case for that one?

Comment: ...Why?  There's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for a good reason; if an insert would fail, an update makes sense.  A select, on the other hand, would not -- and code doing an insert wouldn't expect a result set back.

Comment: @cHao: for example, when you want to use the id of the inserted/existed row, you will want the statement to return a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in one query, but you coul run `INSERT IGNORE <xxx>` and then `SELECT <xxx>`. The `IGNORE` makes it ignore any rows that would trigger duplicate key errors instead of halting.

Answer (score 1):

No. You will have to watch for the duplicate key error then issue your `SELECT` query.

It'd be quite problematic if that existed since `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries are meant to modify data and `SELECT` to return a result set. All kinds of drivers/interfaces handle these cases differently for good reason.